# Query tables across multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

All... I need a way to query identical tables across multiple databases. I have roughly 30+ databases and they all have identical tables.

```
    SELECT 
      a.name
      , a.address
      , b.company_id
      , c.part_no
      , c.cost
    FROM accounts a
    JOIN business b on a.whatever = b.whatever
    JOIN crazy c ON b.things = c.things
```

Something simple like this, but across all databases. The focus isn't joining on multiple databases, that's simple, it's running this across all databases simultaneously. There's got to be a simpler way than creating a long drawn out stored procedure, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.alldatabasequery 
AS 

 CREATE TABLE #temp (
 databasename varchar(500),
 name varchar(max),
 address varchar(max),
 company_id varchar(max),
 cost varchar(max)
 )
INSERT INTO #temp 
 EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' NOT IN ( ''model'',''tempdb'',''master'',''msdb'')
  BEGIN 
  SELECT databasename=''?'' 
    , a.name
    , a.address
    , b.company_id
    , c.part_no
    , c.cost
    FROM ?.dbo.accounts a
    JOIN ?.dbo.business b 
    on a.whatever = b.whatever
    JOIN ?.crazy c
    ON b.things = c.things
   END' ; 

SELECT   * FROM #temp 


GO 

EXEC dbo.alldatabasequery
```

Comment: you can skip some databases like  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' NOT IN ( ''model'',''tempdb'',''master'',''msdb'')
BEGIN
    select ''?''
END'

;

Comment: I have attempted the EXEC sp_MSforeachdb without success previously... while it pulls all data it also pulls data into different result grids, wherein I need them all in one grid.  I will try this though.

Comment: create a temp table  and then insert into it , then select from that temp table

Comment: Ok, how do you insert into a temp table from executing a Stored Proc?

Comment: hi take a luk and let me knw any issues, make sure datatypes are rgt with your system

Comment: Thanks Kumar, but that's the issue, I wrote my script almost identically to yours, but recieved an error 'Incorrect syntax near 'master'.'.  Same with the other tables we excluded in the NOT IN clause.

Comment: ohoo  i forgot to write  ?.crazy   question mark on  crazy table i edited the script may be thats the error

Comment: I'm getting a Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near '.'.   I've isolated the issue to the SELECT statement within the EXEC sp_MSforEachDb section.  All other parts work, so I suppose there's in my script, but I can't find it.  I'd post the script but it's a bit lengthy and I've had trouble posting codes in comments.  I think I'm good though.

Comment: post ur script on question section

Comment: The code is too long... I'm unable to post it in this comment.

Comment: try my second answer with cursor

Comment: post your script in ur question section  means  edit ur question and post ur entire script

Comment: Does this copy the values in the temp table or reference them?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
 databasename varchar(500),
 name varchar(max),
 address varchar(max),
 company_id varchar(max),
 cost varchar(max)
 )


DECLARE @statement varchar(max)=''

     declare cur cursor FOR
 select name
   from master.dbo.sysdatabases
  where dbid >4

      open cur

 DECLARE @name  VARCHAR(8000)


      fetch next from cur into @name

      while @@fetch_status = 0

      begin

   SET @statement='SELECT databasename='''+@name+''', a.name
    , a.address
    , b.company_id
    , c.part_no
    , c.cost
    FROM '+@name+'.dbo.accounts a
    JOIN '+@name+'.dbo.business b 
    on a.whatever = b.whatever
    JOIN '+@name+'.crazy c
    ON b.things = c.things'

  INSERT INTO #temp 
  EXEC (@statement)
   fetch next from cur into @name
     end
    close cur
    deallocate cur

SELECT   * FROM #temp
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL runs pretty efficiently these days, it's not as fast as raw sql, but this is very readable and maintainable. You should ditch the `FETCH`. Just use `SELECT @sql = @sql + 'select * FROM [' name + '].dbo.[Table]' + char(13) FROM sys.databases`. Each record will be appended to the variable. You can also `exec sp_executesql @sql`to fire it instead of just having an sp that generates a script.